# TypeError: fetch failed when running npx gltfjsx command React Three Fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm a newbie trying to explore Three JS on react.
When I try to run `gltfjsx` to generate the jsx component that I will be using on my experiment game. I encountered this error, anyone has an idea ? maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I'm using node version 18.19.0

[Type Error: fetch failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n2Mx.png)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested on https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx/issues/153#issuecomment-1216063589
Downgrading to node version 16.16.0 solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using django or next js with standiolony or else you might have this problem

The first thing is this is one is 100% solved.
if it does not work on your S just play around with it

in your gltfjsx just change the url on usegltf to `/static/<what you want to put your file`

and dont forget to put that in the preload too